# How to use a C# class in many projects inside the same solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions, solution, project-reference

I'm learning C# and I don't know exactly how to make a class visible to all projects inside the Solution.

Basically I have many projects, all Windows Forms, all of them have some similarity, so they can share a lot of classes. I think a good approach is put all the shared classes in the Solution folder and make all the project (apps) get the classes from there.

Is this a good approach?

And how to do it?

Another way to do it, I think, is to put all the shared classes in one project (app) and let the other projects refer to that project.

Is there a better approach?

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and this is what my Solution looks like that I haven't been able to share the classes between the projects:
[image]

Comment: You put it in a class library, aka another project and you reference that class library in your projects

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a Class Library project within your solution and put your shared classes in there:

- Right click on your solution in the Solution Explorer ->
  Click `Add` -> Click `New Project...`
  [image: Add -> New Project...]
- Choose `Class Library` (and name the library something in the next step)
  [image: Add a new Library]

Then in each of the projects that you want to access the classes from:

- Right click on `Dependencies` -> Click `Add Project Reference...`
  [image: Right click Dependencies]
- Tick the class library project you created
  [image]

Comment: There is a lot of options like "**Class Library (.NET Standard)**", "**WPF Custom Control Library (.NET)**", etc. I think the best option would be "**Class Library (.NET Core)**", isn't?

Comment: I can see that your other projects are .NET Core, so yes

Answer (score 1):

You create a class library project and in there you would want to add folders where you can name them according to what the classes would do so it is easier to maintain.  Then you would add your classes in the corresponding folder  and in the project that you want to use the class you can add a reference to the project and the class would be accessible as long as it was a public class.